# JQuery: Get SRC for each image that has specific atrtibute

Tags: jquery-selectors

I am wokring on a dialog, where in execution I want to round up all items that have a specific attribute and place an attribute value of their's into a comma delited list.

This is as far as I have gotten, which isnt far.

```
buttons: {
```

'Hook': function(){
  $('.grid_pic:has(border=3)').(loop through id's, grab src, build variable with srcs comma delimeited)

```
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var srcs = new Array();

$('.grid_pic[border=3]').each(function() { 
    srcs[srcs.length] = $(this).attr('src');
});

var result = srcs.join(',');
```

Comment: @David - Don't forget `srcs.push($(this).attr('src'))` as an option...reads a bit clearer, at least in my opinion.

Comment: Fantastic, I appreciate it its dead on. for the looping and variable building. There's a side problem though. 

$('.grid_pic:has(border)').each(function(){alert(1);}); doesn't shout. My images look like this. <img src='http...' border=3 class=grid_pic> 

If I remove the has:border/has:border=3, it shouts.

Answer (score 0):

This is a concise approach to getting it:

```
var commalist = $('.grid_pic:has(border=3)').map(function() { 
                  return $(this).attr('src');
                }).get().join(',');
```